# Pandas fillna with datetime of another column, but with modification

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2018-12-21", "2018-12-22", "2018-05-04"], "price":[100,np.nan, 105]})
```

Out:

```
date       price
2018-12-21  100.0
2018-12-22  NaN
2018-05-04  105.0
```

I'm trying to `.fillna()` by taking the value of Price, of the day before. So in this case, the NaN value will be filled with `100`, because we took the date of the NaN value minus one day.

Comment: `df.price=df.price.ffill()` ..?? if dates are sorted this will work.

Comment: Do you think value `(df.price.ffill())` or day before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2018-12-21", "2018-12-22", 
                            "2018-05-04","2018-05-05",
                            "2018-05-06","2018-05-09"], 
                   "price":[100,np.nan, 105, np.nan, 108, np.nan]})

print (df)

         date  price
0  2018-12-21  100.0
1  2018-12-22    NaN
2  2018-05-04  105.0
3  2018-05-05    NaN
4  2018-05-06  108.0
5  2018-05-09    NaN
```

---

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')

df['price'] = df['price'].combine_first(df['price'].shift(1, freq='d'))
#alternative
#df['price'] = df['price'].combine_first(df['price'].shift(1, freq='d'))
print (df)
            price
date             
2018-12-21  100.0
2018-12-22  100.0
2018-05-04  105.0
2018-05-05  105.0
2018-05-06  108.0
2018-05-09    NaN
```

If need repalce last non missing value (not day before):

```
df['price'] = df['price'].ffill()
print (df)
         date  price
0  2018-12-21  100.0
1  2018-12-22  100.0
2  2018-05-04  105.0
3  2018-05-05  105.0
4  2018-05-06  108.0
5  2018-05-09  108.0
```